# How to find out the space requirements of files to be committed?

Tags: git, size, commit

I'm going to archive an old huge project containing a lot of garbage. I hope I'll never need it again, but I want to put all important things under version control. Because of the chaos in the project, it's not easy to say what are the sources and what can go away (there's no `makefile`, no `make clean`, nothing). *So I'd like to put there nearly everything and consider only the largest files for exclusion.*

How can I list the files to be committed (or to be staged) together with their size?

<sup>I could write a script or whatever, but hope for a simpler solution. I'm working under Cygwin and the only gui available is `git gui` which doesn't show the file sizes. Otherwise it'd be perfect for what I need.</sup>

Comment: "but I want to put all important things under version control" - surely the important things are already under source control?

Comment: No, it's a one-man project by someone not using VC at all. As I work on it I used SVN for my changes only, later converted it to GIT and now I want to add all the other possibly important files, so it's safe somewhere just in case...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try this. It finds all files larger than 1M and sorts them from largest to smallest. The file sizes printed are in bytes:

```
cd ~/files_to_archive
find . -type f -size +1M -printf '%s %p\n' |sort -nr
```

Output:

```
74751072 ./linux-2.6.38-rc4.tar.bz2
34686037 ./git-source.tar.gz
14026384 ./Python-2.7.tar.gz
```

Updated: loop over the files returned by `find` and print their `git` status:

```
git ls-files -t `find . -type f -size +1M |xargs`
```

Comment: But it doesn't tell me if they're already tracked. There is quite a lot of big files there, some of them important, some of them already tracked, big chaos...

Comment: Oops, sounds pretty chaotic!  I updated the answer, hope this is more useful.

Comment: This looks much better except that `git ls-files -t` seems to print nothing at all for untracked files. The man page led me to `git status --porcelain` which prints `??` for such files unless they're are ignored. A simple `grep` and it's solved.

Answer (score 2):

If you've already added the files, within git is the command `ls-files`. The output can be piped in various clever ways to get what you need.  https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-files

I would suggest setting up a .gitignore file to wildcard out any obvious ones before the first big git add.

Using the `-s` switch to list the staged items, get just the file paths, and then uses du to get the file size:

```
git ls-files -s | awk -F' ' '{ print $4 }' | xargs du -ch
```

Removing human from du leaves all the values in kb. Which allows sort to be used, putting the largest at the bottom:

```
git ls-files -s | awk -F' ' '{ print $4 }' | xargs du -c | sort -n
```

The output could then be used to remove large ones

```
git ls-files -s | awk -F' ' '{ print $4 }' | xargs du -c | sort -n
```

To then remove problem files use the `git reset <file>`.
Taking the output, you can decide the rows to remove (this could be done cleverer, but just took the number of rows with tail, and then removed the total with head).

```
git ls-files -s | awk -F' ' '{ print $4 }' | xargs du -c | sort -n | tail -7 | head -6 | awk -F' ' '{ print $2 }' | xargs git reset
```

Answer (score 1):

To a first approximation, `du -sk .` at the top of the directory tree will give you the space needed.  After you do `git gc`, it might be an overestimate.

But you should have been using version control long before you reached the point of retiring the project.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know about Git, but if you're using Mercurial, you could use a combination of:

```
ls -laS
hg status
```