# Check total size of stage files in sourcetree

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

Is there a way in sourcetree to check the total size of stage files? This is for knowing if the stage files are still too big or to confirm if I really ignored all the big files in my project.

Comment: If there is no way to do this from SourceTree, you can follow this link to check file sizes from the bash: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5214625/how-to-find-out-the-space-requirements-of-files-to-be-committed

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I already used a script to tracked big files from explorer(and I found them). I want to know if there is a feature in sourcetree or any tool that could show the total size of files I'm going to commit so I could trim down further by removing least important files in the project. I'm planning to use that regularly before committing/pushing in git. I guess this will be very useful for us. I hope sourcetree already has this feature.